# Count the Occurences of a text for the whole spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where in every column I have a list of names. They can repeat, and whats even worse - cells can contain some additional text (apart from the name).

What I want to do is count the occurrences of the name in the whole spreadsheet (only looking at the name, omitting the potential additional text). Is Possible?

I tried the formula =UNIQUE, but it does not work vertically (I'm working with Google Sheets)

Example of a document https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1STtJr0yisSeuv2w8_JVgQABAL5EDzI8aFmH8Vp2cOko/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet.

Comment: Is this a one-off event, or something to be repeated?

Comment: Just once, ok give me a sec I'll share the document

Comment: Can the name occur more than once in the same cell? And what about if the string is part of a longer string, does it still counts?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1STtJr0yisSeuv2w8_JVgQABAL5EDzI8aFmH8Vp2cOko/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: No it cant occur more than once, but it can have additional characters - look at the example

Comment: Please edit the spreadsheet to display how a successful outcome would appear.

Comment: Im assuming your looking for `=COUNTIF(SearchRange,"*SearchCriteria*")` Notice the wildcards `*` to tell the formula there can be pre- or exceding characters.

Comment: Ok, but I would have to make this kind of separate formula for every single name, so its not possible to make it more 'atomatic' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Countif, Arrayformula, and Regexreplace to accomplish this task

Assuming you have the data range from A2:E12 and the prefilled unique names starting from A14

***Formula***:

```
=countif(ARRAYFORMULA(regexreplace($A$2:$E$12,".\(.*","")),A14)
```

Copy the formula until the last row

Hope it helps!

Comment: _and the prefilled unique names starting from A14_ How were these names generated? And how did you data cope with the two sets of five columns of data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that others will provide a much more elegant solution but this takes the data as presented in the spreadsheet and can be implemented in just a few minutes.

1. Paste this formula in Cell F3

   `=FILTER({A3:A13;B3:B6;C3:C5;D3:D5;E3:E5;A18:A21;B18:B20;C18:C20;D18:D20;E18:E19}, LEN({A3:A13;B3:B6;C3:C5;D3:D5;E3:E5;A18:A21;B18:B20;C18:C20;D18:D20;E18:E19}))`

This creates a single column list compiled from the various smaller lists.

2. Highlight the range of names created in Column F (based on the test data = F3:F41), click Copy,
3. Highlight cell G3, click Paste special (Paste Values only) - this converts the formula to a list for entries.
4. Paste this formula in Cell H3 - this removes any data in brackets
   `=left(G3,iferror(search(" (",G3)-1,len(G3)))`
5. Copy the formula down as many rows as there is data in Column G
6. Paste this formula in cell I3 - this lists the unique names
   `=unique(H3:H41)`
7. Paste this formula in cell J3 and copy down as many rows as there is data in Column I - this counts the number of instances of each unique name in the master list.
   `=COUNTIF(H:H, I3)`

---

[image]